# Submit multiple jobs one after another

Tags: bash

I have to submit a 5 jobs one after another.

Here is my command -

```
INPUT - 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004

docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-year {INPUT}
```

I need to basically run the docker command for each of the INPUT's -

```
docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-data 1000 ||

docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-data 1001 ||

docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-data 1002 ||

docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-data 1003 ||

docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-data 1004
```

Above is my solution, thinking if there is a better way to do.

Comment: Maybe `for INPUT in 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004; do docker run -d --net ${NETWORK} ${IMAGE}:${TAG} populate_data --for-year ${INPUT} ; done` ?

Comment: thanks, the docker run should run one after another and not in parallel.

Comment: @user1050619 Why do you think they would run in parallel?

Comment: In your code you use `docker ... || docker ... || etc`, i.e. if one `docker` fails, the rest would not be run. Is that a feature that you'd like to keep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that Bodo suggested in a comment runs 5 commands, one after the other:

```
for INPUT in 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004; do docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year "${INPUT}"; done
```

or, expanded out:

```
for INPUT in 1000 1001 1002 1003 1004
do 
  docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year "${INPUT}"
done
```

This assumes you've already set reasonable values for `$NETWORK`, `$IMAGE`, and `$TAG`, of course.

The loop above will run these commands, in sequence:

```
docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year 1000
docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year 1001
docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year 1002
docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year 1003
docker run -d --net "${NETWORK}" "${IMAGE}":"${TAG}" populate_data --for-year 1004
```

If you wanted to run the commands in parallel, you'd add a `&` to the end of the `docker` command.